# string replace without href in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>

</head>
<body>
<a href="hello.html">hello</a>
<script>
var str=document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML=str.replace(/hello/g, "hi");</script>
</body>

</html>
```

In this code hello.html and hello will change hi.html and hi. I don't want to replace href="". How to write regular expression for that ?

Comment: You *could* use jQuery `$('*')` and then replace each element's `html()`. But it would be rather expensive and not straight-forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex replace wil do what you want:

```
<script>
var str=document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML=str.replace(/(>[^<]*)hello/g, "\1hi");
</script>
```

But I think it is still fragile, and any solution with regex replaces in `.innerHTML` will be... Remember that regexes are always a hacky solution when trying to solve problems which involve html/xml parsing.

Answer (score 0):

What do you need this for?  Am I guessing correctly when I say that you want to replace all the text content of the document?

In that case, I would suggest getting a list of all content nodes from the DOM (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)’s accepted answer for two ways to do this, one with jQuery and one without).

Using that, you could then apply your function to update each text node's contents:

```
var textNodes = getTextNodesIn(el);
for (var i = 0; i < textNodes.length; i += 1) {
    textNodes[i].innerHTML = textNodes[i].innerHTML.replace(/hello/g, "hi");
}
```

This would leave all the HTML attributes unaffected. If you want to adjust those as well (excepting, of course, any `href` attribute), you could expand the `getTextNodes` function to include attributes (excepting `href` attributes) in the returned list of nodes.